# seamless upgrade virtualbox from 4.2.0to 4.2.12

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I downloaded "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ("Precise Pangolin") AMD64" from VB [download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) page
using Ubuntu Software Center to upgrade but it says:

> conflicts with the installed package 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso'

Normaly I'm using `apt-get` but that don't work for VB.

Can you share information how to upgrade vb 4.2.0 -> 4.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` package. This will download on demand if required.
2. Install the new version (tip: you could add the virtualbox repository to keep apt-getting - see further down the download page)
3. Install the Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack which comes under a separate license but is still monetarily free and available on [the main download page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: Hi thansk for the reply.
So is this the procedure:
1: apt-get remove dkms
2: download the file from "https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads"
4: In order to fully update your guest system, open a terminal and run 
apt-get update
as root followed by 
apt-get upgrade
5: Install DKMS using 
apt-get install dkms
6: Reboot your guest system in order to activate the updates and then proceed as described above.

Answer (score 1):

So is this the procedure:

```
sudo apt-get remove dkms
```

Download the file from virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

In order to fully update your guest system, open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install DKMS

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Reboot your guest system in order to activate the updates and then proceed as [in Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/308137/527764)

Answer (score 1):

The package `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` is used by the official Ubuntu packages of VirtualBox to provide the ISO image of the VirtualBox guest additions. This image must be distributed as a separate package, because it is not published under a Free Software license.

The Oracle packages of VirtualBox, however, provide the guest additions ISO image directly, and not in a separate package, so the `virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` is not needed if you use the Oracle packages, and it should be removed prior to installing them.